# How can I use async/await with jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, async-await

I use the following code:

```
function getForm() {
    var container = $("<div/>");
    //.......
    var s = jqBS3Input("idToBeSet", "select", null, "In charge");
    container.append(s);
    s = s.find("select");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/ThirdParty/Users",
        async: false
    }).done(function(data, status, jxqhr) {
        data.Data.forEach(function(r) {
            s.append($("<option>" + r.FullName + "</option>"));
        })
    });
    return container;
}
```

I would like to do the following instead:

```
function async getFormAsync() {
    var container = $("<div/>");
    //.......
    var s = jqBS3Input("idToBeSet", "select", null, "In charge");
    container.append(s);
    s = s.find("select");
    var resps = await $.get("/ThirdParty/Users");
    resps.always(function(data, status, jxqhr) {
        data.Data.forEach(function(r) {
            s.append($("<option>" + r.FullName + "</option>"));
        })
    });
    return container;
}
```

but I can't get it running this way

How can I use async/await with jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is:

```
try {
    var users = await $.ajax({
        url: "/ThirdParty/Users"
    });        
    users.Data.forEach(function (r) {
        s.append($("<option value='" + r.Id.toString() + "'>" + r.FullName + "</option>"));
    });
} catch (err) {

}
```

Do not be disturbed by the `Data`, the return of the call is an object :

```
{
    ExitCode: 0,
    Data: [/* ... */]
}
```